# Connecting a Firebase database to front-end app: using correct language

Tags: firebase

My university senior design capstone project is to design an amber alert app with many added features. My job on my team is to write the database. I am currently using Firebase and using Node.js to get the project started. My teammates that are working on the front end are using Dart code for an Android app and a website. Right now I am using the auto-generated HTML file for testing the database.

Do I need to change the language (to Dart?) that I am using so that the database can run with both versions of the app?

I'm currently running Firebase normally with HTML and Node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all communication between your work and that of the front-end team happens through the database, and you have agreement on the meaning of the data in the database, then it doesn't matter what platform/language/technology you use to write to the database.

It is quite common for projects that use Firebase to have both native apps for iOS and Android *and* web apps, all interacting with the same data.